# Android: How to animate several views from different activities after finish()?

Tags: android, xml, transition

I would like to have a scaling-animation of the view of the new activity parallel to the moving buttons and ImageView of the old activity in different directions that are moving out of the screen. 
overridependingtransition() needs xml resources but afaik you can't code e.g. scaling for individual views.
And with Java code, I can't start a new Activity(with Animation) and simultaneously start the animation of the old Activity.
How could i achieve that? 
preferably with XML coding

Here is an illustration from what i want to do:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1jqg.png

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/overview.html

Comment: I already read PropertyAnimation View Animation tween and so on, but didn't find a solution for this problem. If i use overridependingtransition, i can only animate the WHOLE activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe looks like a transition between two activities. You can use the new activity transition's API. Take a look here: https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#Transitions
Keep in mind the compatibility level is 21. It will only work on lollipop devices. 
If you want to be compatible below 21, you can try implementing it on your own.

- First step is to override the transition by calling overridePendingTransition(0,0) right after startActivity()
- Second step is to make your new activity's background transparent and place the views you want to animate. 

  For example if you want an imageview from your first activity to be scaled up and moved to a new place in your new activity, you can send the coordinates and size of the imageview to the new activity thanks to the intent, then move and scale down your imageview in new activity to overlap the imageview in the previous activity (since the background is transparent). 

  To animate it to its real size, you would just animate the scaleX() scaleY() to 1 (original size in the new activity), and translationX() translationY() to 0 (original position in the new activity) for its position.
- Then after the layout of the new activity you can animate the views into their new position. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/overview.html

Comment: What am I supposed to do in step 2 after making background transparent? Place all Views from old AND new activity  in this new activity and animate or making three activities where the second activity is only for animating?

Comment: @user3642735 I've edited my answer. Keep in mind what you are doing is not easy. In order to place a view from position A in the first activity to position B in the new activity, you need to send the coordinates A to the new activity, get the coordinates of the view in activity B, do the substraction x and y (B.x - A.x and B.y - A.y) and use setTranslationX(), setTranslationY() from the result to place the new view on top of the old one.

Comment: do i need the positions? i'm using a linearlayout with weights. honestly i don't understand what to do sorry >.< so your solution is to put the buttons from ActivityOld into ActvityNew and animate them there? do you mean it this way?